# Issue with URLSession Throwing "NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired" and "The server requires a client certificate" for 403 Error Code

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, cfnetwork

When making network requests using URLSession, the application encounters a specific issue related to the 403 error code. In this scenario, instead of receiving the expected response from the server, the URLSession throws the error "NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired" and provides the message "The server requires a client certificate." Consequently, the response and data obtained from the server are nil, despite the fact that all other error codes are handled correctly.

I have tried to handle the response before it handle by the URLSession using some URLProtocol and URLSessionDelegate etc

Comment: Do you have a client certificate for credential ? If you have, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371066/when-using-client-certificate-authentication-why-do-i-keep-getting-nsurlerrordo.